# Cannot set property 'view' of undefined Extjs4

Tags: extjs, view, extjs4, migration, extjs2

I trying to update code from extjs2 to extjs4, but I have an error and something wrong with `grid`.

```
var grid = new App.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    columns: gridColumns,
    frame: false,
  //autoExpandColumn: 'name',
    autoHeight: true,
    loadMask: true,
    bbar: pagingBar,
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true,
        scrollOffset: 2,
        grid: {
            isTree: false
        }
    }
});
```

I had a problem with 'isTree' property before, so, I added this property that would move on, but now, Google Chrome return error in ext-all.debug.js 102947 line::

```
 me.selModel.view = me;
```

Comment: please remember to upvote and also to mark answers Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you should not set grid property in your vieConfig although its difficult to tell whats happening because you are extending your own class not the default grid panel. There is no problem with isTree property typically so get rid of unnecessary configs - its how you get yourself in trouble :)

If you just follow along from an example you'll see the config lines are minimal. And I snuggest you do the same.

Comment: Thanks @dbrin. I Followed the advice and created new question with more details, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298109/cannot-read-property-istree-of-undefined-extjs-4

Comment: You didn't have to do that, yo can just edit your original question. Feel free to mark this question as answered though.